# Gmail "send mail as" with OAuth2

Tags: gmail, oauth

I used to use the "send mail as" option on my gmail account to send emails through my company email. However, they disabled the legacy authentication and now only work with OAuth2.

I tried re-adding my email but got the following error

> Authentication unsuccessful, basic authentication is disabled.

Is there any way that I can import another account to gmail with OAuth2?